# Play audio from speaker and bluetooth earpiece simultaneously flutter

Tags: flutter, audio, bluetooth, speaker

Is it possible for the audio to be played from both the speaker and a bluetooth earpiece in android and iOS devices using either flutter or native ?

I found a way using flutter_audio_manager to switch between them but what I need is the sound to be played from both at the same time